# Tradução de Editar Resumo / Edit Summary

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Quando fazemos uma edição num post existe um campo para o resumo do que fizémos.
Neste momento este campo está traduzido para "***Editar resumo***".

Penso que devêmos melhorar esta tradução que em Inglês é *Edit Summary* e, conforme a sua própria descrição, comprova que a mesma está mal traduzida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### In English:

This translation is wrong.

It translates *"Edit Summary"* to the verb "Edit the summary", instead of "summary of the edition"

**Please change to** `Resumo de edição`

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro:

***Resumo de edição***

Ou somente "***Resumo***", caso a equipa do SE ache que é muito longo para o CSS.